# tkinter's radioButton appear to lose configuration with state="disabled"

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to implement status lights in my app, for the moment only 4 : (Error, Ready, Working, Computing). With a color for everyone, everything looks good to me but when I  change it a few times they appear to lose all color, and multiple are selected at once which should not be possible since they share the same variable and have different values.

You can try and execute the following code: when you press the "Calibrate" button the signal "Working" works fine but when it comes to the "Computing" button everything goes wrong and even more when the "Ready" button is supposed to come back

I guess it has to do with how I manage the state of the radioButton maybe the order of state change is important? Is there a better way to do status light with tk or ttk?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class MainAppGui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("TEST")

        self.buildGUI()

        self.lift()

    def buildGUI(self):
        #Variables tk

        self.varEtat = tk.IntVar()

        #Widgets init

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="ABC")
        
        self.exitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.quit)
        self.calibrateButton = tk.Button(self, text="Calibrer", command=self.CalibrateButtonPushed)

        self.ErrorSignal = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Erreur", variable=self.varEtat, value=-1, selectcolor='red', state='disabled')
        self.ReadySignal = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Pret", variable=self.varEtat, value=0, selectcolor='green', state='normal')
        self.WorkingSignal = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Travail", variable=self.varEtat, value=1, selectcolor='orange', state='disabled')
        self.ComputingSignal = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Calcul", variable=self.varEtat, value=2, selectcolor='yellow', state='disabled')
        
        self.logBox = tk.Text(self, state="disabled")
        
        #Grid setup

        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        
        self.exitButton.grid(row = 0, column = 10)
        self.calibrateButton.grid(row = 1, column = 10)

        self.logBox.grid(row = 1, rowspan = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 9)

        self.ErrorSignal.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        self.ReadySignal.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
        self.WorkingSignal.grid(row = 6, column = 3)
        self.ComputingSignal.grid(row = 6, column = 4)

        #Complete initialisation

        self.signals = [self.ErrorSignal, self.ReadySignal, self.WorkingSignal, self.ComputingSignal]

    def setSignals(self, value):
        assert( isinstance(value, int) and (value in range(-1,3)) )
        if value == -1:
            i = 0
        elif value == 0:
            i = 1
        elif value == 1:
            i = 2
        elif value == 2:
            i = 3
        for k in range(len(self.signals)):
            if k==i:
                self.signals[k].config(state="normal")
            else:
                self.signals[k].config(state="disabled")
        self.varEtat = value
        for s in self.signals:
            s.update()

    def appendToLogBox(self, message):
        self.logBox.config(state="normal")
        self.logBox.insert("insert", message+'\n')
        self.logBox.update()
        self.logBox.config(state="disabled")

    def CalibrateButtonPushed(self):
        self.appendToLogBox("Launching Calibration...")
        try:
            CalibrationRoutine(self)
        except Exception as e:
            self.appendToLogBox("Error : {}".format(e))
        else:
            self.appendToLogBox("Calibration Done")
        finally:
            return

def CalibrationRoutine(mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setSignals(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    """
    ...
    """
    mainWindow.setSignals(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    """
    ...
    """
    mainWindow.setSignals(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainAppGui()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `setSignals` function, right after the for-loop:

```
for k in range(len(self.signals)):
    if k==i:
        self.signals[k].config(state="normal")
    else:
        self.signals[k].config(state="disabled")
self.varEtat = value
```

The problem is this line: `self.varEtat = value`. `self.varEtat` is a `tk.IntVar`, but `value` is a plain Python `int`. Replacing an `IntVar` in this way is bound to break your GUI. Replace this line with:

```
self.varEtat.set(value)
```